# Awk - Print complete string while comparing two files

Tags: string, awk, compare, printf

I am looking to print the whole string from file2.txt but it is only printing 77 but not the whole matched string from File2.txt Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

**Script**

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    out = "File3.txt"}
NR==FNR && NF {a[substr($0,1,8)]=$0; next}
function print_77_99() {
    if (key in a) 
      print "77", a[key] > out
}
 $1 == "01" {
    if (FNR > 1) print_77_99()
    key = $4 $3 $2
 lines = ""  
}

  { print > out
    lines = lines $0 "\n"  }  END {print_77_99()}
' File2.txt File1.txt
```

**File1.txt**

```
01  89  68  5000
02  83  11
04  83  9   02
03  83  00
06  83  00
07  83  11  RT0429
01  44  73  8800
02  44  73
04  44  73   02
03  44  73
06  44  73
07  44  11  RT  0789
```

**File2.txt**

```
50006889RT0429 NARD /3010  /E     /C A87545457          /  //                ///11        ///

51002387 NARD /3000  /E     /S N054896334IV          /  //                ///11        ///
```

**File3.txt (Current Output)**

```
01  89  68  5000
02  83  11
04  83  9   02
03  83  00
06  83  00
07  83  11  RT0429
77
01  44  73  8800
02  44  73
04  44  73   02
03  44  73
06  44  73
07  44  11  RT  0789
```

**Desired Output**

```
01  89  68  5000
02  83  11
04  83  9   02
03  83  00
06  83  00
07  83  11  RT0429
77     50006889RT0429 NARD /3010  /E     /C A87545457          /  //                ///11        ///
01  44  73  8800
02  44  73
04  44  73   02
03  44  73
06  44  73
07  44  11  RT  0789
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the function:

```
function print_77_99() {
    if (key in a) 
      print "77", line[key] > out
}
```

You save File2.txt contents in `a` array but later try to read it from `line` array. Use the `a` instead, like:

```
function print_77_99() {
    if (key in a) 
      print "77", a[key] > out
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... now it is giving me only key after 77 which is 50006889RT0429 but i need the whole strong after. Thanks for figuring this out though ;)